# Calling same Shell Script from various python files - looping through multiple arguments

Tags: python, bash, shell, scripting

I will be sending *BASH_ARGUMENTS from python file to a shell script. My goal is to automate downloading jars with single script:

1. Fetch the arguments
2. Read them one by one and search for 2 words in arguments abc_jar_name and abc_jar_path.Similarly I have def_jar_name, def_jar_path ; ghij_jar_name and ghij_jar_path in my arguments, need to do the same process for all.
3. Then fetch the value of the two matched arguments
4. Lastly, I call a function in shell script to download a jar with file name and file path as the parameters.

I know we cannot fetch arguments directly with $abc_jar_name in shell script , if so my work will be very easy. As multiple python files access this bash script, arguments vary everytime so I can't access with $1, $2 as in one file $1 will jar name and other python file $1 will be jar path.

Looking for help. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Hey Anusha, thanks for the description. Would you be able to provide some code that would, ideally, allow us to reproduce what you are trying to do? Also, is it possible that you may be able to refactor your code all into python?

Comment: Do you really have to use bash for this? Can't you download it using only Python?